# React-Apollo Query component variables never update

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to wrap a chart component in a `<Query>` component that retrieves the chart data. The chart component uses the `Query`'s `fetchMore` render prop to append new data to the chart by updating the query's variables.

**The problem I'm having is that the Query component's render prop never seems to update the `variables` argument after `fetchMore` is run with an updated variables argument.**

Is this a bug with `react-apollo`, or am I using `fetchMore` incorrectly?

Here's the render function of the chart:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <Query
      query={gql`
        query Chart($from: Long!, $to: Long!) {
          chartData(from: $from, to: $to) @connection(key: "chartData") {
            ...
          }
        }
      `}
      variables={{ from: this.props.from, to: this.props.to }}
    >
      {({ data: { chartData } = {}, variables: { from, to }, fetchMore }) => {

        const fetchNext = () =>
          fetchMore({
            variables: { from: from + 30, to: to + 30, },
            updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
              const updatedResult = Object.assign({}, fetchMoreResult)
              updatedResult.chartData = [
                ...previousResult.chartData,
                ...fetchMoreResult.chartData,
              ]
              return updatedResult
            },
          })

        return (
          <Chart
            chartData={chartData}
            from={from}
            to={to}
            fetchNext={fetchNext}
          />
        )
      }}
    </Query>
  ) 
}
```

Here's the steps I'm going through:

1. render prop runs with `from = 0`, `to = 29`, and `chartData` as an array of 30 data points
2. trigger fetchMore. Query runs again with `from = 30`, `to = 59`. Response comes back with 30 new data points. The updatedResult is the full 60 data points.
3. render prop runs again. `chartData` is an array of 60 data points as expected, but `from = 0` and `to = 29`, still. I expected them to update to `30` and `59`, respectively. This causes the chart to have the wrong xMin and xMax because the variables aren't updated.

As a workaround, I tried setting component state copies of `from` and `to` inside the `updateQuery` callback, but this causes the `from` and `to` values to be out of sync with the `chartData` until Apollo is finished updating its store.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From some level of complexity render fn is not good place for ... anything other than view.

Take a look at https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/packages/client/src/modules/post/containers/Post.jsx - there is a nice separation of concerns (queries/containers/components) and example covers fetchMore.

Comment: I used the rendered props approach as @dkulkarni and also encountered the component variables not updating. after i rewrite to hoc pattern, it worked. However, i thought the preferred approach going approach is using the rendered props approach? Apollo website's examples are using the rendered props way

Comment: They are simpler at start and good for a (maybe) half of use cases but you quickly fall in rendering query/mutation components hell. Can you imagine a component and query with fetchMore and three or four possible mutations done with query/mutations components? Add a local state and a few event handlers, some conditional renderings and redux ...  :D Components should be simple, otherwise they should be refactored.

Comment: I agree with ya. It can become a spaghetti mess of code. I personally prefer HOC pattern better.

Comment: ... and you can use all react's component lifecycle methods. Upvote? Answer or delete your own question?

Comment: I believe react hooks and in future suspense will be used in conjunction with rendered props way to provide lifecycle methods in functional components. I haven't played with that yet, so not sure if that will result in cleaner codes

Comment: maybe, but IMHO still for less complex use cases